# PHP Warning: Illegal string offset 'tag'

Tags: php, string, offset

I'm trying to fix some bugs in a program that I'm new to:

```
if  (strtoupper($xmlnode["tag"])=="RANDOM"){

    $liarray=array();

    $children = $xmlnode["children"];

    for ($randomc=0;$randomc<sizeof($children);$randomc++){
        if (strtoupper($children[$randomc]["tag"]) == "LI"){
            $liarray[]=$randomc;
        }
    }
```

On the `strtoupper($children[$randomc]["tag"])` I get the error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'tag'
```

Why this is happening and how might I correct it? I can add more code if needed.

Comment: `$xmlnode` doesn't have element 'tag'. Do `var_dump($xmlnode)` to see what is inside

Comment: `$xmlnode` is not an array, it's a string. You might want to look into using a function to split it into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$xmlnode['children']` is a string, not an array.

It's looking for something structured like:

```
$xmlnode['children'] = [
                            ['tag' => 'LI'],
                            ['tag' => 'LU'],
                            ['tag' => 'LA'],
                            ['tag' => 'LO'],
                            ['tag' => 'LE'],
                            ['tag' => 'LR'],
                        ];
```

But you are actually giving it something like `$xmlnode['children'] = "I am a string";`

EDIT: Complete answer:

You first need to check if the current item in the `$xmlnode['children']` array is an array, and not a string, then process only the keys that are an array.

```
$xmlnode['tag'] = 'RANDOM';
$xmlnode['children'] = array(
    " ",
    array(
        'tag' => 'li',
        'attributes' => "",
        'value' => "Tell me a story."
    ),
    " ",
    array(
        'tag' => 'li',
        'attributes' => "",
        'value' => "Oh, you are a poet."
    ),
    " ",
    array(
        'tag' => 'li',
        'attributes' => "",
        'value' => "I do not understand."
    ),  
    " "
);

$liarray = array();
if  (strtoupper($xmlnode["tag"]) == "RANDOM") {

    $children = $xmlnode["children"];

    for ($randomc=0; $randomc < sizeof($children); $randomc++) {
        if (is_array($children[$randomc])) {
            if (strtoupper($children[$randomc]["tag"]) == "LI") {
                $liarray[] = $randomc;
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($liarray);  
}
```

Comment: This is part of the var_dump: { [0]=> string(1) " " [1]=> array(3) { ["tag"]=> string(2) "li" ["attributes"]=> string(0) "" ["value"]=> string(16) "Tell me a story." } [2]=> string(1) " " [3]=> array(3) { ["tag"]=> string(2) "li" ["attributes"]=> string(0) "" ["value"]=> string(19) "Oh, you are a poet." } [4]=> string(1) " " [5]=> array(3) { ["tag"]=> string(2) "li" ["attributes"]=> string(0) "" ["value"]=> string(20) "I do not understand." } [6]=> string(1) " "

Comment: Thanks for the info, I have provided a working sample of your issue with working solution.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the error. Hopefully I'm not sweeping a bigger issue under the rug.